# Displaying the full exception stack (Nativescript)

Tags: nativescript

My NS app crashes.

It displays the stack trace - but only about 20 lines or so. and then ...

That's not enough for me to figure out where it's crashing.

How can I get it to display more depth.

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend using breakpoints and go through the stack that way: https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/debugging/chrome-devtools

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use Sidekick, [Sidekick install](https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/intro/installation), open debug and check its console messages, it does truncate the log but it lets you copy the full log output.